# restrict Editext editing if editext have text already in Dynamic Listview

Tags: java, android

``@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    if (getItemViewType(position) == 1) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trial_remarks, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        TrialAssessmentBean trialAssessmentBean = getItem(position);

        trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwnerRemarks(overAllRemarksData);
        TextWatcherAdapter textWatcherAdapter = new TextWatcherAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                overAllRemarksData = editable.toString();
            }
        };
    }

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.trail_quality_assessment_row1, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.update(position);
    TrialAssessmentBean trialAssessmentBean = getItem(position);
    int totalTrailerOwnerMaxScore = 0;
    int totalSup1MaxScore = 0;
    int totalSup2MaxScore = 0;
    float trialPercent = 0, sup1Percent = 0, sup2Percent = 0;

    if (position == getCount() - 4) {
        if (totalTrialOwner == 0.0 && trialAssessmentBean.getTrialOwnerSum() > 0) {
            trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwner(trialAssessmentBean.getTrialOwnerSum());
        } else {
            trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwner(totalTrialOwner);
        }

        // trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwnerSum(totalTrialOwner);
        if (totalSupervisor1 == 0.0 && trialAssessmentBean.getSupervisor1Sum() > 0) {
            trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor1(trialAssessmentBean.getSupervisor1Sum());
        } else {
            trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor1(totalSupervisor1);
        }
        // trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor1(totalSupervisor1);
        if (totalSupervisor2 == 0.0 && trialAssessmentBean.getSupervisor2Sum() > 0) {
            trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor2(trialAssessmentBean.getSupervisor2Sum());
        } else {
            trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor2(totalSupervisor2);
        }
        // trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor2(totalSupervisor2);

        TrialAssessmentBean trial1 = getItem(position);
```

//            Log.e("Actual Trial Owner Total ::: ",String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getTrialOwnerSum()));

```
        String trialOwnSum = String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getTrialOwnerSum());
        if (trialOwnSum != null && !trialOwnSum.isEmpty() && !trialOwnSum.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0")) {
            viewHolder.trailOwnerEditText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getTrialOwnerSum()));
        }
        String trialSup1Sum = String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getSupervisor1Sum());
        if (trialSup1Sum != null && !trialSup1Sum.isEmpty() && !trialSup1Sum.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0")) {
            viewHolder.supervisor1EditText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getSupervisor1Sum()));
        }
        String trialSup2Sum = String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getSupervisor2Sum());
        if (trialSup2Sum != null && !trialSup2Sum.isEmpty() && !trialSup2Sum.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0")) {
            viewHolder.supervisor2EditText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getSupervisor2Sum()));
        }
```

//            viewHolder.supervisor1EditText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getSupervisor1Sum()));
//            viewHolder.supervisor2EditText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", trial1.getSupervisor2Sum()));

//            viewHolder.supervisor1EditText.setText(sup1Grade);
//            viewHolder.supervisor2EditText.setText(sup2Grade);

```
    } else if (position == getCount() - 3) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount() - 4; i++) {
            TrialAssessmentBean bean = getItem(i);
            //Log.e("trivant score" ,""+bean.getTrialOwnerSum());
            try {
                int maxScore = Integer.parseInt(bean.getMaxScore());
                if (bean.getTrialOwner() != 0) {
                    totalTrailerOwnerMaxScore += maxScore;
                }
                if (bean.getSupervisor1() != 0) {
                    totalSup1MaxScore += maxScore;
                }
                if (bean.getSupervisor2() != 0) {
                    totalSup2MaxScore += maxScore;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (totalTrailerOwnerMaxScore > 0.0) {
            trialPercent = (100f * totalTrialOwner) / totalTrailerOwnerMaxScore;
            trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwner(trialPercent);
        }

        if (totalSup1MaxScore > 0.0) {
            sup1Percent = (100f * totalSupervisor1) / totalSup1MaxScore;
            trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor1(sup1Percent);
        }

        if (totalSup2MaxScore > 0.0) {
            sup2Percent = (100f * totalSupervisor2) / totalSup2MaxScore;
            trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor2(sup2Percent);
        }
    }

    if (position == getCount() - 2) {

        for (int i = 0; i < getCount() - 4; i++) {
            TrialAssessmentBean bean = getItem(i);
            try {
                int maxScore = Integer.parseInt(bean.getMaxScore());
                if (bean.getTrialOwner() != 0) {
                    totalTrailerOwnerMaxScore += maxScore;

                }
                if (bean.getSupervisor1() != 0) {
                    totalSup1MaxScore += maxScore;
                }
                if (bean.getSupervisor2() != 0) {
                    totalSup2MaxScore += maxScore;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        if (totalTrailerOwnerMaxScore > 0.0)
            trialPercent = (100f * totalTrialOwner) / totalTrailerOwnerMaxScore;
        if (totalSup1MaxScore > 0.0)
            sup1Percent = (100f * totalSupervisor1) / totalSup1MaxScore;
        if (totalSup2MaxScore > 0.0)
            sup2Percent = (100f * totalSupervisor2) / totalSup2MaxScore;

        viewHolder.removeTextWatchers();
        viewHolder.titleTextView.setText(trialAssessmentBean.getParameters());
        viewHolder.maxScoreEditText.setText(trialAssessmentBean.getMaxScore());
        trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwnerPercentage(trialPercent);
        trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor1Percentage(sup1Percent);
        trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor2Percentage(sup2Percent);

        String tGrade, sup1Grade, sup2Grade;

        tGrade = getGrade(trialPercent);
        trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwnerGrade(tGrade);
        sup1Grade = getGrade(sup1Percent);
        trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor1Grade(sup1Grade);
        sup2Grade = getGrade(sup2Percent);
        trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor2Grade(sup2Grade);

        viewHolder.trailOwnerEditText.setText(tGrade);
        viewHolder.trailOwnerEditText.setEnabled(false);
        viewHolder.supervisor1EditText.setText(sup1Grade);
        viewHolder.supervisor1EditText.setEnabled(false);
        viewHolder.supervisor2EditText.setText(sup2Grade);
        viewHolder.supervisor2EditText.setEnabled(false);

        trialAssessmentBean.setTrialOwnerGrade(tGrade);
        trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor1Grade(sup1Grade);
        trialAssessmentBean.setSupervisor2Grade(sup2Grade);
```

//            viewHolder.trailOwnerEditText.setText(""+trialAssessmentBean.getTrialOwner());
//            viewHolder.supervisor1EditText.setText(sup1Grade);
//            viewHolder.supervisor2EditText.setText(sup2Grade);

```
        //  View[] views = new View[]{viewHolder.trialOwnerDate, viewHolder.superVisor1Date, viewHolder.superVisor2Date,
        // viewHolder.finalScoreEditText};

        View[] views = new View[]{viewHolder.finalScoreEditText};
        for (int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
            views[i].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        viewHolder.addTextWatchers();
    } else {
        viewHolder.bind(trialAssessmentBean);
    }
    return convertView;
}`
```

Comment: Update your adapter code

Comment: Have you tried viewHolder pattern? can you share your code?